Flutter Animation Controller
I tried to implement list of draggable widget using GestureDetector and AnimationBuilder. But when the particular widget is removed from tree its AnimationController is assigned to next widget in list like those controllers never removed from tree after disposing that widget.
You can see in this video that after removing element from list I reset animationController of that element, but next element's animation resets and that element's animation status is forward to next.
Here is block of that widget which is directly called in ListView.builder.

class _CartItemCardState extends State<CartItemCard> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final CartController cartController = Get.find();
  late AnimationController animationController;
  double positionX = 0, prevPositionX = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Durations.medium2, lowerBound: 0, upperBound: 25.w);
    super.initState();
  }

  void _resetAnimation() {
    animationController.reset();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.w),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.redAccent, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        children: [
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              _resetAnimation();
              cartController.addedItemList.remove(widget.foodModel);
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.w),
              child: Text(
                "Remove",
                style: TextHelper.size14.copyWith(color: AppColors.whiteColor, fontFamily: poppinsBoldFont),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
              if (prevPositionX < details.globalPosition.dx) {
                animationController.value -= 25.w * 0.05;
              } else {
                animationController.value += 25.w * 0.05;
              }
              if (animationController.value < 0) {
                animationController.value = 0;
              } else if (animationController.value > 25.w) {
                animationController.value = 25.w;
              }
              setState(() {
                prevPositionX = details.globalPosition.dx;
              });
            },
            onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
              if (animationController.value < 12.5.w) {
                animationController.reverse(from: animationController.value);
              } else {
                animationController.forward(from: animationController.value);
              }
            },
            child: AnimatedBuilder(
              builder: (context, child) {
                return Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(-animationController.value, 0),
                  child: child!,
                );
              },
              animation: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 25.w).animate(animationController),
              child: ...,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


I tried disposing all controllers but it throws error for next elements animation.
I implemented this in separate widget so that I don't have to manage list of animationControllers.

When you initialize a Controller for a widget, don't forget to call the dispose() method to dispose of the Controller. try this:
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Dispose the AnimationController to prevent memory leaks
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

also in the ListView.builder give a unique key for each item that you are returning, like this:
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: cartController.addedItemList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final item = cartController.addedItemList[index];
    return CartItemCard(
      key: ValueKey(item.id), // Ensure each item has a unique key
      foodModel: item,
    );
  },
);


Yes it works partly. When i remove that element from list all controllers reset automatically.
